# Gradient with respect to vector for non-linear function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

This is from Machine Learning, a loss function with a linear classifier. The point is how to compute gradient w.r.t. $b$.

---

Problem:

Given scalar function $L(x, y; w, b)$. Compute gradient w.r.t. $b$. Where $x \in R^{N\times D}, y \in R^{N\times M}, w \in R^{D\times M}, b \in R^{M}$

$L = \sum_i{ \max (f(x^{(i)};w,b) - y^{(i)}, 0)}$
$f = x \cdot w + b$, where ($\cdot$) is matrix multiplication.

What is $\nabla_b L $?

---

My try:

$\partial L / \partial f \in R^{N \times M}$, right? Since this is partial derivatives by each coordinate in $f$.

$\partial f / \partial b \in R^{N \times M \times M } $, right? Because we compute a gradient per each $f_{i,j}$.

But then we have $\partial L / \partial b = \partial f / \partial b \times \partial L / \partial f$. How to manage those dimensions now and compute the gradient w.r.t. $b$?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I solved this task for my ML model. I read this guide at https://explained.ai/matrix-calculus/#sec:1.6.2 (see section "The derivative with respect to the bias"), but it is about vectors not matrices. So here is to give some intuition for matrices.

$$
\frac{\partial{(x\cdot w + b)}}{\partial{b}} = \left[ \begin{matrix}
J_1 \\
J_2 \\
\dots
\end{matrix}\right] = \left[ \begin{matrix}
\text{diag}(\partial{f_{1,1}} / \partial{b_1}, \partial{f_{1,2}} / \partial{b_2},  ) \\
\text{diag}(\partial{f_{2,1}} / \partial{b_1}, \partial{f_{2,2}} / \partial{b_2},  ) \\
\dots
\end{matrix}\right] = \left[ \begin{matrix}
I \\
I \\
\dots
\end{matrix}\right] 
$$
where $x \in R^{N,D}, w \in R^{N,M}$ matrices, $b \in R^M$ vector, $J_i$ jacobian w.r.t. $b$ on $f_i = x_i \cdot w + b$. Hence we have M identity matrices.

$$
\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{b}} = \left[ \begin{matrix}
\sum_i 1 \text{ if } f^{(i)} > 0 \text{ else } 0 \\
\sum_i 1 \text{ if } f^{(i)} > 0 \text{ else } 0 \\
\dots
\end{matrix} \right]
$$

$\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{b}}$ of $M$ length.